# Node.js Async File System not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm just trying to this simply.

1. Convert and object to a JSON format.
2. Write a file & that Object to JSON data in that new file.
3. Read from that newly created file.
4. Write the read data to another new file

**PROBLEM:**
Some kind of error with data argument of readFile function but i don't know how to resolve it. (Exactly the reason i'm asking this question)

**NODE.JS CODE:**

```
const fs = require('fs')

const object1 = {
    name: "Zaeem Javed",
    age: 21,
    profession: "Web Application Developer"
}

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(object1)
fs.writeFile("jsonDataFile.json", jsonData, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    
})

const readJSON = fs.readFile("jsonDataFile.json", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    console.log(data)
    
})

fs.writeFile("readJSON.txt", readJSON, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Could you tell us the error message? We cannot help you if there's nothing to work with.

Comment: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot where it does not work? I cannot reproduce it on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code solved my problem:**

```
const fs = require('fs')

const object1 = {
    name: "Zaeem Javed",
    age: 21,
    profession: "Web Application Developer"
}

const jsonData = JSON.stringify(object1)

fs.writeFile("jsonDataFile.json", jsonData, (err) => {
    console.log("Write Successful")
})

fs.readFile("jsonDataFile.json", "UTF-8",(err, data) => {  
    const readJSON = data

    fs.writeFile("readJSON.json", readJSON, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
    
})
```